# Notepad++, replace the first and second comma to ":"

Tags: regex, notepad++

In Notepad++, I'd like to replace only the first and second comma (","), by ":".

Example :

```
blue,black,red -> blue:black:red (2 first commas replaced)
blue,black,red,yellow -> blue:black:red,yellow  (third comma still here)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are there cases where there is only one comma?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can do this by replacing this regex:

```
^([^,]*),([^,]*),(.*)$
```

With this:

```
$1:$2:$3
```

For compatibility with cases where there are less than 2 commas, use these:

```
^(([^,]*),)?(([^,]*),)?(.*)$

$2:$4:$5
```

Answer (score 1):

Just two capturing groups is enough.

Regex:

```
^([^,]*),([^,]*),
```

Replacement string:

```
$1:$2:
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kN1oJ8/1)

**Explanation:**

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `([^,]*)` Captures any character not of `,` zero or more times and stored it into a group.(ie, group 1)
- `,` Matches a literal `,` symbol.
- `([^,]*)` Captures any character not of `,` zero or more times and stored it into a group.(ie, group 2)
- `,` Matches a literal `,` symbol.

Comment: Notepad++ uses `$1`, not `\1`.

Comment: @Pietu1998 you can use both

Comment: Okay; I trust you on that, I believe our hasn't ever worked for me though.

Answer (score 1):

Something along this line,

```
^([^,]*),([^,]*),(.*)$
```

And replace with

```
$1:$2:$3
```

Or `\1:\2:\3`

Comment: Perhaps substitute `[^,]+` with `[^,]*`, it's not clear if there is always data between the comma's.

Comment: Changed it per your suggestion @CommuSoft :)

Comment: @Lenny it understands both \1 and $1

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try to capture the parts in groups and then replace them as follows:

```
/^([^,]*),([^,]*),(.*)$/$1:$2:$3
```

How does it work: each line is matched such that the first part contains all data before the first comma, the second part in between the two commas and the third part all other characters (including commas).

This is simply replaced by joining the groups with colons.

Answer (score 0):

A no-brainer; virtually "GREP 1-0-1". Not really an effort.

Just find

```
^([^,]+),([^,]+),
```

and replace with

```
\1:\2:
```

Answer (score 0):

Click on the menu item: Search > Replace

In the dialog box that appears, set the following values...

Find what: ^([^,]+),([^,]+),

Replace with: $1:$2:

Search Mode: Regular expression